# Python Small Ubbi Project

Tags: python

Hello everyone I've been practicing with python for a bit now and found a project named Ubbi. Pretty much the whole goal is, is to add a string 'ub' before every vowel. So my question am i even close to cracking this or should i head another route??

```
def ubbidubbi_word(eword):
    ubword = ""
    for i in eword:
        if i == 'aeoiuy': ubword += 'ub'+eword(i)
        else: ubword += eword(i)
    return ubword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!  However...:

(A) `eword(i)` would **call** `eword` as a function with **argument** `i`, which makes no sense; just use `i` itself, the character you're currently looking at (maybe you're thinking of Javascript here...? but even there the syntax will be different);

(B) `i`, a single character, will **never** equal the string `'aeoiuy'`, as you're checking; rather you should check if `i` is **in** that string (and thus a vowel).

Comment: A fun one-liner to do the task, assuming s is your string:     `ub=''.join([('ub'+s[i] if s[i] in 'aeiouy' else s[i]) for i in range(len(s))])`

Comment: Probably more confusing than helpful... Don't try to understand it if you're only beginning with python :)

Comment: @SmeltQuake agree w/the latter, esp. as it would be puzzling to understand why not just use the simpler , faster `''.join('ub'+c if c in 'aeiouy' else c for c in s)` -- whence the fetish for indexing and listcomp over genexp?-)